# Perl Syntax Error - "use" not allowed in expression line 2

Tags: perl

I'm new to perl and I'm getting this error when I try to compile.

I'm getting this;

```
syntax error at deneme.pl line 1, near "PHP Code:"
"use" not allowed in expression at deneme,.pl line 2, at the end of line
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at deneme.pl line 3.
```

Here is my code;

```
PHP Code:
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::GuiTest qw(:ALL);
use Time::HiRes qw(usleep);
use LWP::UserAgent;


use constant HTKEY => 'a';
use constant START => 2;
use constant STOP  => 1;

my $sleep = 1;
my $cond = 0;

while (1) {
    start() if $cond == 1;
    if (IsKeyPressed(START)) { $cond = 1 }
    if (IsKeyPressed(STOP))  { $cond = 0 }
}

sub start {
    $sleep = 1000000 * (1/as())/2;
    SendKeys(HTKEY);
    usleep($sleep);
    SendMouse("{RIGHTCLICK}");
    usleep($sleep);
}

sub as {
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 }, protocols_allowed => ['https'] );
    my $req = HTTP::Request->new( 
        GET => 'https://127.0.0.1:2999/liveclientdata/allgamedata',
    );
    my $res = $ua->request($req);
    if ($res->content =~ /"attackSpeed": (\d+\.\d+),/) {
        return $1
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question. Always include code ans errors as text, not as images. Images are hard to read, links can break, and people cannot copy & paste the code to give it a try.

Comment: In the future, please include the exact code executed, and the exact error messages received. Also, please don't remove the problem from the question once it's discovered. (I also can't help but feel that you should have been able to fix this if you had tried at all.) Voting to close as a "typo".

Answer (score 2):

Your code starts with:

```
PHP Code:
```

That's not valid Perl. What were you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to delete that part, edited.

Comment: @corei: The image of your original error is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBrwn.png). It says "syntax error near 'PHP Code:'". So that **was** in your code at some point and it **did** cause that error. If you've removed it now, then your code should compile and run.